# Couchdb with SSL and Nginx to reverce the ip

Tags: docker, nginx, couchdb, cloudflare

I have a docker container that contains CouchDB and I want to link it with my domain in Cloudflare to make the connection secure with SSL so, can I use Nginx to reverse the ip of the droplet with the domin of the CouchDB container, or is it better to config the CouchDB  for the SSL.

Answer (score 0):

1-create droplet.
2-docker-compose.yml for CouchDB.

```
version: '3'
services:
couchserver:
image: bitnami/couchdb
restart: always
ports:
- "5984:5984"
environment:
- COUCHDB_USER=admin
- COUCHDB_PASSWORD=pass
volumes:
- ./dbdata:/opt/couchdb/data
```

-docker-compose up

3-Link domain with Cloudflare and make SSL.
4-link the droplet with the domain.
5-Use Nginx to reverse the IP of the droplet with the domain.
6-Install NGINX(not container on the droplet itself) and configure.
sudo apt install nginx
8-and Change nginx config file.
7-sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
root /var/www/html;
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name yourdomain.com www.domain.com;
location / {
proxy_pass http://68.183.5.130:5984; #whatever port your app runs on
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
#pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
# include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
```

Finally your connection will be:(`https://username:password@yourdomain.com/yourDB`)